# How to compare value in json array in android

Tags: android, json

I want to compare this to value to fill selected value in spinner perform edit operation. I am not able to do the same since my value is not compared. I have pasted logcat details also in below. Please check and look into this.

**For loop:**

```
 for (int n = 0; n < subMaterialTypeModelArrayList.size (); n++) {
                            Log.i ("Test","msg: "+subMaterialTypeModelArrayList.get (n).getId ());
                            try {
                                Log.i ("Test","id:"+subid);
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e){

                            }
```

**Logcat Result:**

> 03-01 11:44:40.402 4113-4113/com.example.jjjj.dashboard I/Test: msg :1
>   03-01 11:46:46.284 4113-4113/com.example.jjjj.dashboard I/Test: subid
>   :["1","2"]

Answer (score 0):

```
     Try this way,


     if (subMaterialTypeModelArrayList != null && !subMaterialTypeModelArrayList.equals("")) {
         for (int n = 0; n < subMaterialTypeModelArrayList.size(); n++) {
              if (subMaterialTypeModelArrayList.get(n).getId ().equalsIgnoreCase(subid)) {
                    spinner_name.setSelection(n);
               }
     }
```

Comment: this is multi select spinner

Comment: see this link https://github.com/prsidhu/MultiSelectSpinner/blob/master/multispinner/src/main/java/com/multispinner/MultiSelectSpinner.java  or https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner

Comment: i am using same library my problem I want o show selected value filled at a time of edit operation. but I am not getting filled selected value